# deep learning for stock prediction

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, deep-neural-networks, time-series

I am learning deep learning . Right now I am using MNIST data set, which contains tens of thousands of scanned images of handwritten digits, together with their correct classifications.

My question how to use time series data like stock market data (how to incorporate stock data with neural networks )

My second question how to know which neural networks is suitable for predicting ?

Comment: I think you are looking for a tutorial that explains using stock market data with machine learning. At AI Stack Exchange, the volunteers don't write full tutorials for you on demand, it takes too much effort. I suggest you search for a tutorial and start it. Then, if you hit a problem with understanding any detail, that is where AI Stack Exchange can help you.

Comment: @NeilSlater I am just asking the logic/principle  behind using time series data instead of images/audio in first layer of neural network .   I know the hands-on procedure

Comment: Have you tried searching for "neural networks for time series"? It's not clear how/why you are stuck.

Comment: Or, I threw the exact title of this post into google and the first result was a tutorial on the subject.

Answer (score -2):

Everything can be fed into a neural network as long as you can encode the input and output into tensors.

There are only two model bases in deep learning for every machine learning problem: the regressor model and the classifier model.

For the input tensor, you should encode the time series into a vector. Perhaps you must specify the window size of the input tensor.

Particularly about the output tensor, it's not clear whether your problem is about classification or regression. If its output is the future price in continuous value, then it's a regression, and the output tensor will likely be a future vector relative to the past vector.

If its output is only about whether the price will increase or decrease, then it's a classification problem with two classes (binary classification). Then the vector is likely encoded as 1 (increase) or 0 (decrease) relative to the past vector input.

Comment: give me examples say i have csv data of stocks like open close high low